# IntelliSense: identifier "node" is undefined

Tags: c++

I am having trouble to solve the error. identifier "node" is undefined at the 2nd last line in .cpp file. I want to return the node but the compiler shows the error file please help me someone to solve this.

```
 #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class Node
    {
    private:
        int data;
        Node *node;
    public:
        Node(int, Node *);
        void setdata(int);
        void setnode(Node *);
        int getdata() const;
        Node *getnode();
    };

#include<iostream>
#include"Node.h"
using namespace std;

Node::Node(int Data = 0, Node *n = NULL)
{
    setdata(Data);
    setnode(n);
}
void Node::setdata(int D)
{
    data = D;
}
void Node::setnode(Node *N)
{
    node = N;
}
int Node::getdata() const
{
    return data;
} 
Node Node::*getnode()
{
    return node;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `Node Node::*getnode()` to be `Node * Node::getnode()`? Looks like you might have copy/pasted that `Node::` at the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
class Node {
private:
  // ...
public:
  // ...
  Node *getnode();  // Returning a pointer to a Node, my guess is the * placement
                    // is confusing you
};

// Other implementations

Node* Node::getnode() // Means the same thing as above; * placement is relatively
                      // flexible
{
  return node;  // return type now matches what you're returning
}
```

Your function implementation is written incorrectly is all. The flexibility of * placement can be confusing for beginners, given how strict C++ usually is.